# How to move files in directory, using QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Can we move files from one folders, using QlikView script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after having a look at QlikCommunities, it looks like this is not possible. If you want to trigger a move from QlikView Script you could either use [VBScript](http://community.qlikview.com/message/35012#35012) or [cmd.exe](http://community.qlikview.com/message/68555#68555).

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the below command

```
EXECUTE cmd.exe /c move  "source directory" "destination Directory"
```